# Check if class is a template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates

How can I check if a given type is a specialization of a particular class template? For instance, given

```
template <class T>
struct A {};
```

How can I check if `CompareT` is an `A<*>` for some type `*` in the following:

```
template<class CompareT>
void compare(){
   // is this A ?
   cout << is_same< A<*> , CompareT >::value;     // A<*> ????
}

int main(){
  compare< A<int> >();
}
```

For example, here  `A<int>` should match `A<*>` and print 1.

Comment: [std::is_same](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) ?

Comment: @quantdev yes, but I need is_same that work for this case :)

Comment: "is this A?" Is *what* A? What are you comparing to what?

Comment: Maybe you mean: is the type `CompareT` an instance of the type template `A`? Is there some `X` (any `X`) for which `A<X>` is `CompareT`?

Comment: I meant A<int> = A<*>  (Same class, no matter what specialization)

Comment: You keep writing `A<*>`. What does `*` mean?

Comment: For example, you want `A<int>` and `A<double>` and `A<string>` to be true.  but `vector<int>` and `vector<double>` and `vector<string>` to be false?

Comment: A<*> is A < Any type here >. In other words I want to compare does CompareT (A<int>) is specialized A

Comment: @tower120 There are a few answers already, perhaps it would be productive to add comments there.

Comment: Aha. I think the word "specialized" threw me off. "template specialization" has a specific meaning that is different from the way you're using it. Maybe you should say "instance" or something like that.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid it is, in fact, correct. A template specialization is the type that results from a template instantiation. An *explicit* template specialization is probably what you're thinking about. But I agree that this is all very confusing.

Comment: @Quentin, I had thought that `vector<bool>` was "specialized" but that all other instances of `vector` were (non-special) instances.

Comment: I never heard about template instantiation:) I thought that vector<bool> is specialization of vector<T> .

Comment: @AaronMcDaid (and tower120) *instantiating* a template means generating the final type (the *specialization*) by plugging in arguments for each template parameter. The implementation of the type is picked by pattern-matching its "signature", and the chosen one can be an *explicit* (like `std::vector<bool>`) or *implicit* (from the first and most general declaration) specialization. We further distinguish *partial* and *full* explicit specialization, depending on whether there are template parameters left.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's one where you can provide the template to be matched against :

```
template <class T, template <class...> class Template>
struct is_specialization : std::false_type {};

template <template <class...> class Template, class... Args>
struct is_specialization<Template<Args...>, Template> : std::true_type {};

static_assert(is_specialization<std::vector<int>, std::vector>{}, "");
static_assert(!is_specialization<std::vector<int>, std::list>{}, "");
```

Comment: Note that this won't work for all templates, such as `std::array` which is mentioned in the question this was closed as a duplicate of.

Comment: @Potatoswatter indeed. Non-type template arguments are still annoyingly unflexible.

Comment: Is there any workaround possible with "auto" template parameters in c++ 17? I am trying with no success, but I'm still not a master of c++ templates...

Comment: @NicoBerrogorry somewhat. `auto` can be used to deduce a non-type template parameter's type, so `std::array` can be matched by `template <template <class, auto> class Template, class T, auto S>
struct is_specialization<Template<T, S>>`. However, type and non-type parameters are still incompatible and you'd need to generate a whole lot of these permutations to cover all (reasonable) cases.

Comment: name `is_specialization` is misleading, since specialization means alternative implementation of template for specific type(s). IMO it would be better to use `is_instance_of` or `is_template_of`.

Comment: @MarekR yes and no. Both are called [specializations](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec.general#4.sentence-2), which can be explicit or implicit. I agree that not calling the result of a template instantiation an instance is a bit counter-intuitive, but I prefer to be consistent with the standard.

Answer (score 10):

`CompareT` is a type and `A` is a template. A class can't *be* a template, identically. A class can be a specialization of a template, so I'll assume that's what you want.

Partial specialization can do pattern-matching:

```
template<class T>
struct is_an_A // Default case, no pattern match
    : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_an_A< A< T > > // For types matching the pattern A<T>
    : std::true_type {};

template< class CompareT >
void compare() {
    std::cout << is_an_A< CompareT >::value;
}
```