# std::enable_if - custom type trait that handles types and a template

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if, function-templates, class-template

I have a function template, and a class template:

```
template<typename T>
T testFunction(T argOne, T argTwo) { //Implementation }

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, int> = 0>
class testClass { //Implementation }
```

I want to limit the function to only accepting arithmetic types AND this one (though possibly more in the future) custom class template.

For just the arithmetic requirement this works fine:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, int> = 0>
T testFunction(T argOne, T argTwo) { //Implementation }
```

but does not include the class template. So, I figured I'd simply make a custom type trait:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_valid_v = std::is_arithmetic_v<T> || std::is_same_v<T, testClass>;

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_valid_v<T>, int> = 0>
T testFunction(T argOne, T argTwo) { //Implementation }
```

but this causes the compiler to complain with

```
use of class template 'testClass' requires template arguments
```

because it can't implicitly handle the type used for the template class when the trait template is declared this way. So, while the following compiles:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_valid_v = std::is_arithmetic_v<T> || std::is_same_v<T, testClass<int>> ||
                                                       std::is_same_v<T, testClass<long>> ||
                                                       std::is_same_v<T, testClass<float>> || 
                                                       //...;

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_valid_v<T>, int> = 0>
T testFunction(T argOne, T argTwo) { //Implementation }
```

it is undesirable because I'd have to include a condition for every type the template class can use (everything under std::is_arithmetic).

I tried overloading the type trait like so:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_valid_v = std::is_arithmetic_v<T>;

template<template<typename> class T>
constexpr bool is_valid_v = std::is_same_v<T, NII>;
```

and while both of those compile fine, I still get

```
candidate template ignored: requirement 'is_valid_v<my_namespace::testClass<long, 0> >' was not satisfied [with T = my_namespace::testClass<long, 0>]
```

when trying to use `testClass<long>` (or any type) with testFunction.

How can I create a type trait constexpr with a "wildcard" so that I can achieve:

```
constexpr bool is_arithmetic_v = std::is_arithmetic_v<T> || std::is_same_v<T, NII<...>>;
```

without having to type out a case for every type testClass can be instantiated with? I'm fairly certain what I am aiming for is possible but that I just can't figure out the semantics for it.

**EDIT:**
As @NathanOliver marked this post is *almost* a duplicate of [Check if class is a template specialization? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762958/check-if-class-is-a-template-specialization); however, that post doesn't show how to use its answer with enable_if and a custom template class. If I implement the answer in that post:

```
template <class T, template <class...> class Template>
struct is_specialization : std::false_type {};

template <template <class...> class Template, class... Args>
struct is_specialization<Template<Args...>, Template> : std::true_type {};
```

I can then modify my function template to be:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_specialization<T,std::vector>::value, int> = 0>
T testFunction(T argOne, T argTwo)
```

but as soon as I swap out `std::vector` with `testClass` I get:

```
error: template template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding template template parameter
```

Also, how can I create the shortcut `is_specialization_v` that makes use of `::value` and returns a bool? I am unsure how to use the arguments provided in

```
template <template <class...> class Template, class...Args>
```

to achieve this.

**EDIT 2:**
The error with the solution in the other question seems to be because my class template has an enable_if statement itself. If I remove the requirement so it is just `template<typename T>` then testClass works in the `is_specialization` function. This won't work though because I need that enable condition on testClass.

These small, but significant differences (using all of these particular features at once) are why I asked this question and why it is **not quite a duplicate**.

Comment: @Fureeish this gives `error: use of template template parameter 'Template' requires template arguments` which is similar to what I was getting when I attempted implementing the shortcut myself.

Comment: @Fureeish Unfortunately, this gives the same error. I was trying to use constexpr bool and couldn't avoid this error no matter how I used the arguments.  A different compiler notes: `type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class T, template<class ...> class Template> struct is_specialization'
12:70: error:   expected a type, got 'Template'
12:70: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for 'template<class T, template<class ...> class Template> struct is_specialization'
12:70: error:   expected a class template, got 'Args'`

Comment: @Fureeish It shouldn't be, as the error is thrown from the statement alone, not when I am trying to use the function. This compiles alone and when I use it with enable_if (testing with std::vector for now), but I'm not convinced it is functionally correct: `template <template <class...> class Template, class...Args>
constexpr bool is_specialization_v = is_specialization<Template<Args...>, Template>::value;`

Comment: @Fureeish Didn't catch the hyperlink before sorry, guess I'm blind. When I [try to use that template](https://godbolt.org/z/ZC40Im) in your example it doesn't seem to work unless I'm using it wrong. [Another online compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/HyVv49WvH) throws a similar error to the one I'm getting with MSVC in Qt creator just from the declaration alone (the error I mentioned above)

Comment: After getting faimilar with your code, I must admit that I was wrong and, unfortunately, I do not know how to simplify the calls. I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58027884/type-traits-v-variable-template-utility-order-fails-to-compile) in this regard. I also deleted my previous comments since it was getting a little too chatty.

Comment: Solution: `template <class T, template <class...> class Template> constexpr bool is_specialization_v = is_specialization<T, Template>::value;`. Simple, but I overlooked it.

Comment: @Fureeish Thanks for staying commuted. Exactly what I needed and takes care of the second half of my question.