# How can I check if a template specialization is a child class of a base template?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Using [Check if class is a template specialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762958/check-if-class-is-a-template-specialization), I can check if a class is a specialization of a template.

Using [`std::is_convertible<A*, B*>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible), I can check whether A is a child class of B.

How can I implement `is_convertible_specialization`, something that would do:

```
template<typename ... Args> 
class Base {};

template<typename ... Args> 
class Child : public Base<Args...> {};

template<typename ... Args>
class Unrelated{};

static_assert( is_convertible_specialization<Child<int, int>, Base>{} ); // True
static_assert( is_convertible_specialization<Unrelated<int, int>, Base>{} ); // False
```

I've tried a few things already, but my skills in TMP are rather lacking, so I don't think I've come close. My "best" attempt is:

```
template<template<class...> class ChildTemplate, template<class...> class Template, class... Args>
struct is_convertible_specialization : std::false_type {};

template<template<class...> class ChildTemplate, template<class...> class Template, class... Args>
struct is_convertible_specialization<ChildTemplate<Args...>, Template> : std::true_type {
    is_convertible_specialization() {
        static_assert( std::is_convertible<ChildTemplate<Args...> *, Template<Args...> *>());
    }
};
```

in which I attempt to "nest" assertions in a way that seemed simple to me. This provides me with the following error message, which seems vaguely sensible, but not really comprehensible for me.

`Template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close.

First, the template parameters of the primary template (but not the specialization) must match the way you want to use your template:

```
template <typename ChildTemplate, template<class...> class Template>
```

Next, if the pointers are *not* convertible, the specialization of `is_convertible_specialization` should evaluate to `false` instead of triggering a static assertion. You can do that by inheriting from `std::is_convertible_v<...>` instead of `std::true_type`, and removing the custom constructor.

Here's the result:

```
template <typename ChildTemplate, template<class...> class Template>
struct is_convertible_specialization : std::false_type {};

template <template<class...> class ChildTemplate, template<class...> class Template, class... Args>
struct is_convertible_specialization<ChildTemplate<Args...>, Template>
    : std::is_convertible<ChildTemplate<Args...> *, Template<Args...> *>
{};
```

Comment: Brilliant! I hadn't found `std::bool_constant<>` yet. Thanks.

Comment: Would it work to simply inherit from `std::is_convertible<...>` instead of `std::bool_constant<std::is_convertible<...>::value>`?