# Overload function template using a templated type

Tags: c++, overloading, c++20, function-templates, function-templates-overloading

I have a given function like this:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
T function(const F& f) const;
```

This function has various overloads, some of them concept based. Similar to the following:

```
template <typename T, std::integral F>
T function(const F& f) const;

template <typename T, std::same_as<double> F>
T function(const double& f) const;
```

Now I would like to add an overload using a templated type, similar to the following:

```
template <typename T, std::same_as<std::vector<V>> F>
T function(const std::vector<V>& f) const;
```

For this to work I need to specify the `V` type. But I could not find a syntax that allows specifying `V` without breaking the code.

The functions are called like this:

```
T result = function<T, F>(f);
```

This means, the template types are provided explictly and the overloads may not vary the number or order template parameters or else the compiler will complains.

How can this be solved?

Comment: But, exactly, what do you want specify about `V`?

Comment: @max66 V only needs to be know before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your own concept.

Adopted checking whether a class is a specialization from [Check if class is a template specialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762958/check-if-class-is-a-template-specialization) and added a requires-clause to only accept the standard allocator.

```
template <class T, template <class...> class TT>
struct is_specialization : std::false_type {};

template <template <class...> class TT, class... Ts>
struct is_specialization<TT<Ts...>, TT> : std::true_type {};

template <class T, template <class...> class TT>
concept specializes = is_specialization<T, TT>::value;

template <typename T, specializes<std::vector> F>
T function(const F& f) const requires specializes<F::allocator_type, std::allocator>;
```

Unless the template-arguments may be provided manually, overload-resolution should work with the following overload though:

```
template <typename T, class V>
T function(const std::vector<V>& f) const;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to a compiler to test this at the moment, but this should suffice:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename V>
T function(const std::vector<V>& f) const;
```

Comment: I suggested this in my comment but I'm not sure it's what OP is after.

Comment: @einpoklum Based on OP's comment on the other answer, I believe you're right. Oh well, I answered the question that was actually asked...

Comment: Just changed the question like you have proposed. Care to remove your answers since it doesn't answer the question anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using *requires-clause*?

```
template <typename T, typename F>
  requires std::same_as<std::vector<typename F::value_type>, F>
T function(const F& f) const;
```