# How to write generalised constexpr std::is_same_v

Tags: c++, templates

Lets have a template

```
template <class T>
class X
{}
```

Lets say I use 2 variants of that template

```
using Xint = X<int>;
using Xbool = X<bool>;
```

In some other code inside a template, there is an if:

```
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Type, Xint> || std::is_same_v<Type, Xbool>)
  <process X>
else
  <process generic>
```

This works, but the obvious goal would be to not have to name all of the Variants of X in the if, but to write it generically, I was hoping for something like:

```
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Type, X<classT>>)
  <process X>
else
  <process generic>
```

Which compiles for me, but just doesn't work, it always ends up in the else branch.

Comment: [Does this satisfy your requirements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762958/check-if-class-is-a-template-specialization)

Comment: The code you posted is pseudocode and doesn't compile.  Can you post a [mcve], because your problem could be "typo" or "need to write new machinery", and I cannot tell from your pseudocode which it is.  If it is a typo, writing new machinery is a bad plan, and I don't see how your code that looks like that could compile and not work unless it is a typo or a design error.