# How to create a class template member function for only a std::array type

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++14, stdarray

I have a class template

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
  T value;

  // methods
  // ...
}
```

For the case where `T` is a `std::array`, I want to be able to call `std::array::at` on an instance of `Foo` directly.
For example I want to be able to do

```
Foo<std::array<int, 5>> bar;
// ...
int x = bar.at(0);
```

However, currently I have to use `bar.value.at(0)`.

Is it possible to define the function `Foo::at` only for the case where `T` is a `std::array`, which simply returns `value.at()`? I don't know how this is done since std::array itself has template arguments. Ideally I don't want to rewrite the entire template for the specialized case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try something? Writing the method to work for `std::array`s is simple and straightforward. Not providing the method for all other `T`s is the tricky part

Comment: Add an `at` function to the class and use SFINAE to constrain it.  You should be able to adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762958/check-if-class-is-a-template-specialization) to tell you if `T` is a specialization of `std::array`

Comment: Is it important that, say, `Foo<std::vector<int>> bar; bar.at(0);` **not** work? If it's OK for the method to work for both (and any other type that provides a suitable `at` method), then just implement `at` as if `T` is an `std::array`.