# C++ non-literal type error with if constexpr

Tags: c++, constexpr, if-constexpr

### Setup

I defined two template classes `ContainerA` and `ContainerB` as shown here

```
template <class... T>
  class ContainerA{
  public:
    constexpr explicit ContainerA(T... data) : data_(data...) {}
    constexpr explicit ContainerA(std::tuple<T...> data) : data_(data) {}

    constexpr std::tuple<T...> getDataA() const { return data_; }
    constexpr std::size_t getSize() const { return sizeof...(T); }


  protected:
    const std::tuple<T...> data_;
  };


template <class T>
  class ContainerB{
  public:
    constexpr explicit ContainerB(T data) : data_(data) {}

    constexpr T getDataB() const { return data_; }

  protected:
    const T data_;
  };
```

as well as another class, derived from the above:

```
template <class O, class... I>
  class BiggerContainer : public ContainerA<I...>, public ContainerB<O>  {
  public:
    constexpr explicit BiggerContainer (O dataB, I... dataA) : ContainerA<I...>(data...), ContainerB<O>(dataB) {}
    constexpr explicit BiggerContainer (O dataB, std::tuple<I...> dataA) : ContainerA<I...>(data), ContainerB<O>(dataB) {}
  };
```

### What works just fine so far

First, I want to initialize a `std::tuple`, i.e. holding one object of each of above's classes:

```
constexpr auto tup = std::make_tuple(ContainerA(1,2,3), ContainerB(0), BiggerContainer(0,1,2,3));
```

Next, I want to be able to evaluate an if statement at compile time. As far as I know this can be done with `if constexpr`.
This if statement shall check if either a `ContainerA`, `ContainerB` or `BiggerContainer` is stored at a certain place in `tup`.

```
template <class T>
struct IsBiggerContainerType: std::false_type {};

template <class... T>
struct IsBiggerContainerType<BiggerContainer<T...>> : std::true_type {};

template <class T>
constexpr bool isBiggerContainerType(T /*var*/) {
  return IsBiggerContainerType<T>();
}

int main() {
  constexpr auto element = std::get<2>(tup);
  if constexpr (isBiggerContainerType(element)) {
    std::cerr << "Hello World" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

**So far, all this work's just fine!**

### Problem

Now I have an additional class `Test` that shall get a tuple alike `tup` and then be able to evaluate an `if constexpr` like above in a friend function.

```
template <AbovesClassesConcept... PS>
class Test{
public:
  explicit Test(std::tuple<PS...> data) : data_(data) {}

  <template idx = 0>
  friend constexpr void evaluate();

private:
  const std::tuple<PS...> data_;
}

<template idx = 0>
constexpr void evaluate() {
  // ... some tuple iteration stuff that works just fine
    
  constexpr auto element = get<idx>(data_); 
  if constexpr (isBiggerContainer(element)) {
    // ... do something with element
  }

  // ... some other tuple iteration stuff that works just fine
}
```

**But** when creating an instance of `Test` like this

```
constexpr auto tup = std::make_tuple(ContainerA(1,2,3), ContainerB(0), BiggerContainer(0,1,2,3));
constexpr Test test(tup);
```

#### I get an error:

**Constexpr variable cannot have non-literal type 'const Test<ContainerA<int, int, int>, ContainerB, BiggerContainer<int, int, int, int>>**

Is the problem the non-const friend function or is there a problem somewhere else? I couldn't figure it out so far. Any help is appreciated!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't marked the constructor of `Test` as `constexpr`, like you have with your other classes, so this error message when trying to treat it as `constexpr` shouldn't be surprising.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overthinking it. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/31763111/9072753 .

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template <class T, template <class...> class Template>
struct is_specialization : std::false_type {};
template <template <class...> class Template, class... Args>
struct is_specialization<Template<Args...>, Template> : std::true_type {};

//

template <class... T>
struct ContainerA {
    constexpr explicit ContainerA(T... data) {}
};

template <class T>
struct ContainerB {
    constexpr explicit ContainerB(T d) {}
};

template <class O, class... I>
struct BiggerContainer : public ContainerA<I...>, public ContainerB<O>  {
    constexpr explicit BiggerContainer (O dataB, I... dataA) :
        ContainerA<I...>(dataA...),
        ContainerB<O>(dataB) {

    }
};

constexpr std::tuple<ContainerA<int, int, int>, ContainerB<int>,
        BiggerContainer<int, int, int, int>
        > tup = std::make_tuple(
    ContainerA(1,2,3),
    ContainerB(0),
    BiggerContainer(0,1,2,3)
);

template<int IDX, typename TUPLE>
using isBiggerContainer = is_specialization<
    std::remove_const_t<std::tuple_element_t<IDX, TUPLE>>,
    BiggerContainer>;

int main() {
    static_assert(is_specialization<std::remove_const_t<std::tuple_element_t<0, decltype(tup)>>, ContainerA>{});
    static_assert(!isBiggerContainer<0, decltype(tup)>{});
    static_assert(!isBiggerContainer<1, decltype(tup)>{});
    static_assert(isBiggerContainer<2, decltype(tup)>{});
}
```

> that shall get a tuple alike tup and then be able to evaluate

`element` is the runtime element, `decltype(element)` is the type.

```
if constexpr (is_specialization<decltype(element), BiggerContainer>{}) {
```