# Allow metafunction to take templates with non-type and type template arguments regardless

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts, template-templates, non-type-template-parameter

I created a `is_specialization_of` concept based on the type traits found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762958/check-if-class-is-a-template-specialization). The concept checks if a type is a specialization of a certain template. Those work well in all cases where I just have type template parameters. But in cases where I have non-type template parameters I get an error and I was wondering if is possible to extend the concepts so that they always work, regardless if the parameters are type or non-type.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIJIAzKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/ilpGQIhYZEsMXGJtpj2jgJCBEzEBNk%2BflxVNZn1jQTFEdGxegoNTS257cM9faXlEgCUtqhexMjsHOYJocjeWADUJgluyAjEAqgH2CYaAIIbWzuY%2B4cAbpgOJBdXt2abDNteewOR2G%2BHOCUuNwA9JD9j9ksQmMAWExdgJVl8vgRMCxkgYsU83FicXjHkCCABPZKMViYAB09Iuu22TAUClIuwpVOYbE%2BN2GxC8Dl2eAUAH0FFTkHgxHgAF5MWoMXYgXYgkAgKhiJSizmkgDsVj1ABEDlYbpjsbiFaTDkSrfiyZTqWx6bTGczWbsACqWkns3Xcun03bXYjABRPCHXfmCgjCsUSt7S2hyhWZIHe33W9k%2B4nWoGh8Ouz7g5WqgjodUEAWYHVO/YGkzG00Ym52kkE9vWztOwPF0seiO5%2B2Yf29mmukNhhS865oP6YZJxkXiyXJ1OK0WoKhPI3x1dJmXyxVA4d%2BqdFhng9XPMReTAt81P65dh2HNUgdKy2tx8Jjrk0iGs4xkKjCOBSGIGg2JoJGatxtlmb6EuObDeoyxCYAAjl4eAYRGK6JlKR5pgIW5UECYGEOSObAdWsaogQCCxJBcG7GxDFMcQEDzsMaFmAAbLsmBzF87FiWWbG1k2FhCdBonsdJcnPmJXpCaKj63M2sGtvB1yhHGyKhBAInmo2NxidC3oICKuzoKgmAKAwYAcHGADuJAANbyWxqCMbEqLSZREGHAEwqCBcxlNjBcHebsllekxuz8LQtCoK5oTALs7nEB5EaMUswAILFlkfq87zEEC%2BmMmVGnFTCeA7jxWKqPCuwQARa7EZu25AqVbxEGQtlvLQuoQGVIngnMDasexllifC%2BlUBA5hmAAEtUqVgGAJgAKxuAwK0TTNbGWVFOlRRwCy0JwO28H4HBaKQqCcG41jWKqSwrKSPw8KQBCaJdCweSAO0aPonCSHdANPZwvAKCAYP/Q9l2kHAsAwIgKCoDidCxOQlBoDj9BxOGzDJAoCC%2BaQWDPHgqwAGp4JgrkAPJcpwv00CNsTwxAUTQ1EoSNOSHO8ILzDEOSLNRNo/Wi6QhNsIILMMLQIvI9T2KGMA4ga/gGEOHgrzwxrmCqG8XhYtD%2BnVNDKZRAikseFg0PVngLCiwsVAGOGjPM2zjDy/wggiGI7BSDIgiKCo6ga7o7QGEYKBvZY%2Bh4FE8OQAsqBLpkJsALQggcRqmJY1hmBouz5wA6mItBVyzEb50uJyYEw6Bw9U/WZC4DDuJ4rTxDtgR99MAxxEkqTpIqYx%2BJIw9T4UDBj2UgxJHY3d1CMzQD7k88dJvDDdE0K%2BzOv2%2Bz0Ptjb6fa8LAon2rPM4McLdpD3Y9z0cLsqgABz8fnfikhdjAGQMgNqdEGAeSmhAXAhASCwgSFwOYvAkZaDmEDEGYNrocEhqQD2oN37Qy/nDBGf0AYLDRpjJYBBkiW3xtxbGyRcbEHCDSTgf8AFAJAWA3YXAzC0jMLwTA%2BABp4ErO0YOwhRDiAjlI6Oahobx1IK5BEyRPYvzfh/XgX8WaWzoXGbcP9/6AOAaA8BEBIHQLah4Im/kNjINQRQhYTF26DGMi/PBBCwbaJhhwUhiNnGkGBoQnBCQoYaxIeQ5GGCX5CKIZE2G0T0ELFeMQdIzhJBAA)

```
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
// #pragma once

template <template <typename...> class, typename>
struct is_specialization : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> class Template, typename... Args >
struct is_specialization< Template, Template<Args...>> : std::true_type {};

template <template <typename...> class Template, typename... Args>
concept is_specialization_of = is_specialization<Template, Args...>::value;


template <std::size_t N, typename A>
struct entity
{ };

template <typename T> requires is_specialization_of<entity, T>
struct other
{
    other(const T& e)
        :   e_{ e }
    { }

    T e_;
};


int main()
{
    // This doesn't work
    other o{entity<2, int>()};

    // The following works though
    // std::vector<int> vec;

    // if constexpr (is_specialization_of<std::vector, decltype(vec)>) {
    //     printf("Hello!\n");
    // }

}
```

Error

```
<source>:20:32: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<template<class ...> class Template, class ... Args> concept is_specialization_of'
   20 | template <typename T> requires is_specialization_of<entity, T>
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:20:32: note:   expected a template of type 'template<class ...> class Template', got 'template<long unsigned int N, class A> struct entity'
```

I tried to declare the template template parameter as auto... without luck:

```
template <template <auto...> class Template, auto... Args>
concept is_specialization_of = is_specialization<Template, Args...>::value;
```

Comment: What you need is the so-called Universal Template Parameter ([P1985](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1985r3.pdf)).